# What signature is required for an event handler in Polymer.dart 1.0.0-rcx

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

`<child-element>` fires an event like

```
fire('spoken', detail: {'message': this.$['myInput'].value});
```

`<parent-element>` handles the event like

```
<div on-spoken="heard">
  <child-element></child-element>
  <div>{{message}}</div>
</div>

// @eventHandler <= 1.0.0-rc.1
@reflectable
void heard(Event e) {
  set('message', 'heard: ' + e.detail['message']);
}
```

This results in

> Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'
>
> NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'call'
>   Receiver: Closure: (Event) => void from Function 'heard':.
>   Tried calling: call(Instance of 'CustomEventWrapper', _LinkedHashMap len:1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event handler is expected to have this signature

```
// @eventHandler <= 1.0.0-rc.1
@reflectable
void heard(Event e, var detail) {
  set('message', 'heard: ' + detail['message']);
}
```

To make it more convenient for situations where you also want to call the event handler directly from your code and don't use the arguments inside the handler you can make one or both parameters optional.

```
@reflectable
void heard(Event e, [_]) {
  set('message', 'heard');
}
```

or

```
@reflectable
void heard([_, __]) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: The reasoning for this is that in the old version of Polymer we allowed you to omit arguments from your method signature that you didn't use. This was a feature of the `smoke` library, but the `reflectable` library which is now used for reflection does not provide this feature.We could add a workaround on the polymer side, and likely will at some point, but it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: I think it's fine. It just took a while to figure out how it is supposed to be used and found a SO q+a is a good way to make a note where I find it when in need ;-)

Comment: I do find this CustomEventWrapper annoying! Event handler signatures changed very much versus 0.5 and it's not mentioned in a migration guide. If a KeyboardEvent is expected, you don't get away with putting that type in the signature. Now you have to do KeyboardEvent e = ev.original; where "CustomEventWrapper ev" is in the signature, if you want to keep lint and WebStorm happy. Without a good debugger you're pretty much lost and can't even write an event handler any more!